# Server Adding Extra Parameters to Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, query-string

I tried it with different frameworks from custom build to PhalconPHP.

It seems sometimes, on some servers when there is a specific parameter value, server is adding extra parameters to the query string.

This happens with `index` word specifically.
For example if the URL is like this; `http://example.com/index` and when I dump `$_GET` values I get this;

```
array(1) {
  ["_url"]=>
  string(29) "/redirect:/public/index.html/"
}
```

However any other URL value which doesn't start with `index` acts as expected. For example when I dump `$_GET` for `http://example.com/my-page` 
I get;

```
array(1) {
  ["_url"]=>
  string(29) "/my-page"
}
```

My .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # CloudFlare SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L]

    # Redirect WWW to NON-WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Public Root
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I googled and checked SOF for solutions but I wasn't so lucky.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually the “fault” of MultiViews.

Try and disable it by adding

```
Options -MultiViews
```

to your .htaccess.

For more info on this topic, check
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#options
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/content-negotiation.html#multiviews